Upgrading to XCode Version 16.0 beta 6 (16A5230g) and couldn't build flutter project
i installed the macOS Sequoia bêta 15.0 (24A5331b) so i was forced to update XCode to Version 16.0 beta 6 (16A5230g) , i couldn't build and run my flutter project that i used to run and build before.
i got build failed but no error is shown and it shows "IOS 18 not installed" in the list of connected devices (i am connecting my Iphone 14 pro ( IOS 17.6.1 )
is there a way to downgrade XCode or any other solution ?

Sequoia doesn’t seems to support Xcode 15, you likely have to revert your Mac. Generally when you are interfacing with 3rd parties you have to wait to upgrade things until they catch up.

If you encounter the same error, you can find your solution by visiting this link.
https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/2283#issuecomment-2367389122
